# WebRTC Not Working Between Android AVDs I want to know the cause

Tags: android, android-emulator, webrtc, android-virtual-device, stun

I want to emphasize that it only doesn't work between Android AVDs. I know the solution involves using a TURN server, but I can't seem to find the root cause.
I want to know the root cause.

I thought there would definitely be relevant information in the official documentation, but I couldn't find any. It's possible that I'm not searching correctly.

If anyone knows the cause of the issue I'm experiencing, please help me out. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.